# Typescript function that accepts generic as argument but returns multiple types

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

I have a very simple function that accepts a single parameter that can be of any type. I only check if this parameter is defined or not, but if it isn't, it returns an error if type HttpError (from SvelteKit).

```
function safe<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg ?? HttpError;
}
```

I'm trying to make it return both the argument type and the HttpError in the case that the argument isn't defined. I tried with generics, but I get the message that 'HttpError is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to HttpError'.

Is there any way to work around this? I tried to make a union return but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably that you are returning a class when you should be returning an instance. I.e.

```js
function safe<T>(arg: T) {
    // error creates an `HttpError`
    return arg ?? error(400, 'Bad Request');
}
```

There also is no need to type the return value explicity, it will be inferred automatically. In this case the compiler will also add the null check and infer:

```js
HttpError | NonNullable<T>
```

You also might want consider just throwing the error, depending on how the function is to be used.

---

By the way, if you want the explicit return type for clarity, in VS Code you can just write the function without the type first and then apply the rewrite quick fix "Infer function return type" and it will add the correct type for you.

Comment: so we can add arg type in `Bad Requst ${type of arg}`   will work ?

Comment: @ThanHtutZaw It's just a message, so it can be anything.